# Magento user account types (buyers/sellers)

Tags: php, javascript, magento, e-commerce

I am setting up an eCommerce store based on Magento. I need to make it so that the user log in functionality is two fold; one for buyers, and one for sellers.

The end goal is to have a file upload form accessible to sellers, but not to buyers. Sellers will use this upload to upload some files which I will then make available as products on their selling pages.

Comment: FYI, Magento now has its own StackExchange site: http://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento has customer groups concept.

So you create two customer groups and depending on which customer logged in you place an if condition and get your resulted form displayed.